# Responses is empty while calling web services via zend framework 2.3

Tags: php, curl, zend-framework2

I am a newbie in zendframework 2.3. In my app i need to call web services. and i used class Zend\Http\Client() ... everything is fine... but reponse is empty..  It works in curl call via core php

```
$request =
'<?xml version="1.0"?>' . "\n" .
'<request><login>email</login><password>password</password></request>';

$client = new Zend\Http\Client();
$adapter = new Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl();
$adapter->setOptions(array(
'curloptions' => array(
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
)
));

$client->setUri("https://xyz/getCountries");
$client->setAdapter($adapter);
$client->setMethod('POST');
$response= $client->send();

echo "<pre>\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: You have `$respons = $client->send();`. It should be `$response = $client->send();`

Comment: yeah ... but it is spelling mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use directly the `Http Client` by setting the `CURLOPT_POST` and `CURLOP_POSTFIELDS` options in the `Client` and not in the `Adapter`, just like this :

```
$data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' . "\n" .
        '<request><login>email</login><password>password</password></request>';

$client = new Zend\Http\Client('https://xyz/getCountries');
$client->setMethod('POST');
$client->setRawBody($data);
//set the adapter without CURLOPT_POST and CURLOP_POSTFIELDS
$client->setAdapter(new Curl());
$response = $client->send();
```

And then get the response in output (your code is wrong, you should use `$response->getBody()`) :

```
echo "<pre>\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($response->getBody());
echo "</pre>";
```

Here's a good [post](http://www.franzdeleon.me/2013/11/how-to-use-zf2s-curl-http-adapter.html) on how to use the Curl Http Adapter in Zf2.

Comment: can u tell me which version...   i am useing 2.2.7 version... It is not working ... core php code works fine ... but it is not... i have tried this... but it could not help me...

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP client requests don't return a string, they return a `Zend\Http\Response` object. To see the output you probably want:

```
echo "<pre>\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($response->getBody());
echo "</pre>";
```

Also, personally I would try and avoid setting options on the adapter directly. It makes it more difficult to switch adapters should the need arise.

Answer (score 0):

```
$request =
'<?xml version="1.0"?>' . "\n" .
'<request><login>email</login><password>password</password></request>';

$client = new Zend\Http\Client();
$adapter = new Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl();
$adapter->setOptions(array(
'curloptions' => array(
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request,
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
)
));

$client->setUri("https://xyz/getCountries");
$client->setAdapter($adapter);
$client->setMethod('POST');
$response= $client->send();

echo "<pre>\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($response->getBody());
echo "</pre>";
```